# SQl Server Query with add column value in rows as addition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Table ExamSubjects

```
ExId,SubId,GroupId,SubOrder,NoQuestions
1    2     1       1      60
1    3     1       2      60
1    1     2       3      120
```

I want an output in way that column NoQuestions must be added top next column based on groupId

```
ExId SubId,StartNo,EndNo
1     2     1       60
1     3     61      120
1     1     1       120
```

Is There any other method other than using loop and temp table.Currently i am using while loop to generate the output

Comment: Very tempted to try solving this with the new functionality in OVER clause in SQL Server 2012 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ExId,SubId,ISNULL((SELECT SUM(NoQuestions) FROM ExamSubjects ex2 WHERE GroupId=ex1.GroupId AND SubOrder<ex1.SubOrder),0)+1 AS StartNo,ISNULL((SELECT SUM(NoQuestions) FROM ExamSubjects ex2 WHERE GroupId=ex1.GroupId AND SubOrder<ex1.SubOrder),0)+NoQuestions
FROM ExamSubjects ex1
```

Comment: I think you are missing the ,0's in the ISNULL()s.

Comment: @larsts Yup, I sure was.  Updated answer.